# RubyPython exec() и eval()

Tags: python, ruby

Как возможно обратиться к python функциям exec() или eval() из Ruby c помощью RubyPython?

Answer (score 0):

> ## Known Problems
>
> Built-in Python methods requiring a top-level frame object (such as eval(), dir(), and the like) do not work properly at present.

Видимо никак.